# Heroku gives me webpack and node js error on push

Tags: node.js, heroku

Heroku gives me errors suddenly, 
It worked fine for about a month with same settings, yesterday after editing some minor things in the project and uploading to git it gave me error when pushing to heroku master:

```
Creating an optimized production build...
       Failed to compile.

       ./src/sections/welcome/welcome.css
       Error: Didn't get a result from child compiler


npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ghvinieri@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the ghvinieri@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.KO8no/_logs/2019-03-20T10_43_07_497Z-debug.log
-----> Change to Node.js build process 
       Heroku has begun executing the "build" script defined in package.json
       during Node.js builds.
       Read more: https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/1573
-----> Build failed

       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys

       Some possible problems:

       - Node version not specified in package.json
         https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version

       Love,
       Heroku

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

I tried putting node version in package.json, deleting package.json, node_modules are included in gitigonre, even tried to copy repo from heroku master which contained older code that works on heroku right now, then editing it and uploading; it still gives error, it makes no sense to me. it works on heroku right now with the same settings though when I upload with a minor change it gives errors. could anyone help me with this? Im stuck, looked up all possible solutions none of them work.

Comment: Is your Node version specified in `package.json`? Heroku very clearly suggests looking at that in the error message.

Comment: I tried indicating it and it didn't work. also when I clone heroku repo from heroku git it comes with package json which has no node version in it though it works on heroku right now, the website has no errors; I dont remember putting node version in package json earlier but things worked without it, its only now it started to break. also " Error: Didn't get a result from child compiler" this error began to appear, not sure why that is.